# Firebase - Web Chat App sign in button doesn't work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I use windows 8. I would like to build an app using [this guide.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#0). On 7 step, I change main.js file. My file content is below :

```
FriendlyChat.prototype.initFirebase = function() {
  this.auth = firebase.auth();
  this.database = firebase.database();
  this.storage = firebase.storage();
  this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged.bind(this));
};


FriendlyChat.prototype.signIn = function(googleUser) {

   var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
};

FriendlyChat.prototype.signOut = function() {
  this.auth.signOut();
};

FriendlyChat.prototype.onAuthStateChanged = function(user) {
if (user) { // User is signed in!
  var profilePicUrl = user.photoURL; // Only change these two lines!
  var userName = user.displayName;   // Only change these two lines!
  ....
}

FriendlyChat.prototype.checkSignedInWithMessage = function() {
  if (this.auth.currentUser) {
    return true;
  }
  ....
```

I create a project using firebase console. I click "Add Firebase to your web app" and click the snippet. I paste it to index.html file. The file content is below :

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAbtFJIZZxExBZec5XjsIE6p_TK4x-NDLE",
    authDomain: "xxx-65704.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx-65704.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "xxx-65704.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>    
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>    
</body>
```

I run "firebase serve" command on cmd terminal. I open localhost:/5000and the page is below :

[image]

It doesn't display web chat. So I open we-start/index.html, I click "Sign in With Google". But I cannot sign in. I don't know how to fix this problem. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below initializations works for me.

```
{

  "hosting": {
    "public": "./",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `firebase.json` does not specify the correct directory for where the files are located. In your case it should be:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "we-start",
    ...
```

See the [reference section of the Firebase Hosting documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public) for a full description of all properties.

Comment: I change firebase.json under web-start, but the result doesn't change.. New content is below : `"hosting": {
    "public": "web-start",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }`